# How do I compare 2 numbers differ by 10% or more?

Tags: formula

Trying to create an alert that pops up when 2 number values differ by more than 10%.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: can you provide more information?

Comment: I haven't tried much because I'm new to salesforce syntax. If I have 2 records of numerical value, I want to be able to write a formula that will compare if they are within 10% of each other.

Comment: Have you done the trailhead on the subject? It would be the best place to start. Please take some time to read [ask] and update your post afterwards. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to write is a formula, then the syntax could be this one  (assuming you're looking for a boolean result):

`Number1__c > (Number__2 * 1.1) || Number1__c > (Number__2 * .9)`

This will return true if Number1 is larger than 110% or lower than 90% of Nubmer2. You may want to invert the numbers.

(I Have not tested this, so it's possible that you may encounter a minor syntax error)